# Using VBA to add multiple entries in sequential order in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am fairly new to access, and I am having trouble figuring out how to accomplish the task of adding multiple new entries/rows. I have very little VBA experience, but I am trying to work things out before seeking help.

Here is the set up: Our database will be an issue tracking database, and I have most of the forms worked out, the only issue is adding multiple units at once.

For example, I have a table called tblUnit, which has columns for ID, Serial Number, Assembly (model number), SoftwareRevision, HardwareRevision, RevNotes, Notes, and Buyer.

On the form I have created to add entries to this table, I have an additional unbound text box listed as Quantity.

What I would like to happen is to use a button that will kick of the VBA code below. All of the columns would be the same except for Serial Number (I haven't figured out how to do this quite yet).

I was thinking a form could work were you fill out all of the information, and then put in the Number/Quantity of units to add, and then the first serial number in the batch. Then it would add X number of new entries, with the Serial Numbers increasing incrementally after the first.

Here is the code so far

```
Private Sub cmdSubmitUnit_Click()

Do While Me.QtyUnitAdd > 0  

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord  

Me.SerialNumber = Me.SerialNumber + 1  

Me.QtyUnitAdd = Me.QtyUnitAdd - 1  

Loop  

End Sub
```

It is increasing the serial number by one for each quantity, but not in the way I hoped. If I start with a serial number of 696001 and enter a Quantity of 100, I end up with only one record with a Serial number of 696200, and not one hundred records numbered 696001 through 696200. I tried to supplement the code with a NewRecord command to make it clear I was needing a new record in each loop, but after the first one I get an error that the Part Number has not been entered. I am guessing this is where pulling or keeping the data entered previously would useful, but I have not found a code that would allow me to do this.

I would appreciate any advice or assistance in correcting my code to accomplish what I am aiming for, if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after much research and trial and error, I have the answer. I've  posted the code below in case it would be useful to someone else, or if anyone has recommendations for improvement.

```
Private Sub cmdSubmitUnit_Click()

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSave


Do Until Me.QtyUnitAdd = 0

DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Me.SerialNumber = Me.SerialNumber + Me.QtyUnitAdd.Value - 1
Me.QtyUnitAdd = Me.QtyUnitAdd - 1
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSave

Loop

End Sub

Private Sub PartNumber_AfterUpdate()
  PartNumber.DefaultValue = Chr(34) & PartNumber.Value & Chr(34)
End Sub

Private Sub DateBuilt_AfterUpdate()
  DateBuilt.DefaultValue = Chr(35) & DateBuilt.Value & Chr(35)
End Sub
Private Sub Notes_AfterUpdate()
  Notes.DefaultValue = Chr(34) & Notes.Value & Chr(34)
End Sub
Private Sub SerialNumber_AfterUpdate()
  SerialNumber.DefaultValue = Chr(34) & SerialNumber.Value & Chr(34)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have located another approach that seems to work well, utilizing Temporary Variables. By adding an AfterUpdate event to each field in the form setting a TempVars based on the value entered, the submittion of the form code now looks like this:
    Private Sub cmdSubmitUnits1_Click()

```
txtQuantity1.DefaultValue = Chr(34) & txtQuantity1.Value & Chr(34)



   Set TestDB21 = CurrentDb
   Set rstUnits = TestDB21.OpenRecordset("tblUnits")


rstUnits.AddNew
rstUnits("SerialNumber").Value = Me.txtSerialNumber.Value
rstUnits("PartNumber").Value = TempVars!Assembly
rstUnits("SoftwareID").Value = TempVars!SWRev
rstUnits("HardwareID").Value = TempVars!HWRev
rstUnits("Notes").Value = Me.txtNotes.Value
rstUnits("DateBuilt").Value = Me.txtDateBuilt.Value
rstUnits.Update


Do Until Me.txtQuantity1.Value = 1

Me.txtSerialNumber.Value = Me.txtSerialNumber.Value + 1
Me.txtQuantity1.Value = Me.txtQuantity1.Value - 1
txtSerialNumber.DefaultValue = Chr(34) & txtSerialNumber.Value & Chr(34)

rstUnits.AddNew
rstUnits("SerialNumber").Value = Me.txtSerialNumber.Value
rstUnits("PartNumber").Value = TempVars!Assembly
rstUnits("SoftwareID").Value = TempVars!SWRev
rstUnits("HardwareID").Value = TempVars!HWRev
rstUnits("Notes").Value = Me.txtNotes.Value
rstUnits("DateBuilt").Value = Me.txtDateBuilt.Value
rstUnits.Update

Loop

DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCreateUnit"
```

By adding an upon close event to the form itself of remove all temp variables, this seems to work much more nicely.